How to install exfatprogs on ubuntu 20.04?
I ran the commands
sudo apt-get update
and then
sudo apt-get install exfatprogs
This is the output I get:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package exfatprogs

I have universe enabled.

Do you know for sure this is a package that is in the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories? A Google search for the package brings me to this Ubuntu official web site. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=exfatprogs

@David It can be found here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/exfatprogs

@David I guess you are right - it is only for the newer versions of Ubuntu. I have to install exfat-utils instead (which I just managed to do).

What is the contents of your sources.list file? cat /etc/apt/sources.list

@moo pasted them here

You are using focal. exfatprogs is not available in focal. Looks like another poster has answered the question which package you need to install instead

@moo anyway, I just realized that it's impossible to use exfatprogs on ubuntu 20.04, as they require libc6 >= 2.34 and as far as my understanding goes that is not possible on ubuntu 20.04. Guess I will have to use a VM or update.

As we found with David, exfatprogs is only for newer versions of Ubuntu. For 20.04 I have to install exfat-utils instead:
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils

You may want to accept the answer as well.

@David, says I can only accept my answer in 2 days, so I will do that. Thanks for your help!
